# Internet coax cable split before the modem

Tags: internet, ethernet, cat5

I'm moving in a new flat and I was told by the owner that the internet is ready. However when I checked it out there was only a coax connector waiting for me. I was expecting an CAT5 (UTP) outlet.

I think what they've done is they split the internet coax cable before the modem.

What can I do now? Do I need to get another modem from my cable provider? Will that even work?

Thank you for your help. If any additional info is required please let me know.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to provide your own cable modem.

Comment: Also, did they actually say "the internet is ready" or "it is internet-ready"?  The latter often means that it is suitable for you to be able to *order* internet and have it work. not that it's necessarily provided.

Comment: No, I was told that internet is provided and am infact charged for it every month. I think the cable was just split wrong, I would expect an UTP cable to be connected from the Router to my apartment and not the coax cable.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on the technology used.

If they had an internet connection that then went via ethernet to each apartment, then, all you would need to do is plug in your computer and/or router.

The term internet ready can be mis-leading.

I highly doubt they have just split the cable in an ordinary way, it probably means they have a deal with an ISP who installed their equipment throughout the building and you have the option to take up a subscription with them.

Comment: Is there a router I can connect to the coax cable? I thought they all use UTP (CAT5) cables / connectors. Or is there a coax - cat5 (utp) bridge of some sort? Can you provide me with any examples?

Comment: In Canada where I live, Shaw Cable provides a Motorola modem which has a co-ax input, and an Ethernet output. I imagine this is the same anywhere in the world where co-ax Internet access is provided.

Comment: This generally isn't something you can do yourself / the router (or modem) will authenticate/similar, so, you need to take out a service with a provider. As Randolph said, pretty much anywhere that uses Coax will provide you a router when taking their service. (There are odd times when this won't be the case - but, that is unlikely)